# TimeZoneInfo.Local on XP

Tags: c#, timezone

I have code like this which runs fine on windows 7...

```
TimeZoneInfo _timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
```

It doesn't work on XP SP3. The error given is...

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.EntryPointNotFoundException'
>   occurred in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to find
>   an entry point named
>   'GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation' in DLL
>   'kernel32.dll'.

Looking at the help for the function GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation I see that it's only available on vista+

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not in XP, then you're not going to be able to use it, and sadly it's not just a case of copying a DLL over from a different box.

Can you use this method of getting the TimeZone ? MSDN says its supported in XPSP3 and higher:

```
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try the older timezone class and see how it goes.

Comment: I've added a new answer to follow up to this since the text was too long for this box...